# Reading Linux distribution name from filesystem or command

Tags: linux

I need to collect some system info from [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) machines and decide what to do based on some distribution/version -specific conditionals.

To simplify my example, I concocted a fictitious `my_function_display_operating_system` function. It is a useless function but it frames the problem:

1. detect the general OS type ([osx](/questions/tagged/osx), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), etc.)
2. detect some version information about the OS
3. detect the distribution *friendly name*

Point `3.` is what I most need help with.

Is there a reliable way to read a string indicating the host [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) distribution name?

I am using `/etc/issue` in the example below as I know of no other way, or set of ways, to get to this information.

I am happy with a *it depends* answer, I can build a quite involved `case` `esac` switch statement if need be.

I just need to know where to look, and I can't download/install VMs for all the distros I know of to "look around" and/or [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) for the name..

---

```
# Displays operating system.

function my_function_display_operating_system() {
  local operating_system
  case $my_global_os_type in
    OSX)
      printf -v operating_system \
                'OS X v%s (build %s)' \
                $(sw_vers -productVersion) \
                $(sw_vers -buildVersion)
      ;;
    Linux)
      local -r linux_kernel_version=$(uname -r)
      printf -v operating_system \
                'GNU/Linux (kernel %s)' \
                "$linux_kernel_version"
      if [[ -f /etc/issue ]]; then
        local -r distribution=$(cat /etc/issue | sed 's/ \\n \\l//g')
        operating_system+="\nDistribution: $distribution"
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      operating_system=Unknown
      ;;
  esac
  printf "Operating system: $operating_system\n"
}
```

---

Sample output:

---

```
> my_function_display_system_information
Operating system   GNU/Linux (kernel 3.5.0-25-generic)
Distribution       Ubuntu 12.10
System memory      1 GB
Bash               v4.2.37(1)-release
Vim                VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 26 2012 16  45  54)
# ... etc ...
```

---

Comment: Yes! It's a dup!

Answer (score 0):

Very similar advice given here:

https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running

The short answer:

```
 ls /etc/*{release,version}
```

Various distributions will spit out different formats, unfortunately there's no single uniform system.  The answer above lists much more specifically some of the most common files to look for.